# Access Visual Studio's default Icon inside a VS project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, icons

I need to set the default icon that VS uses for the project to another Icon withing my project.  Is there an easy way to access this?

I tried going to .Properties.Resources but it doesn't seem to be there.  Is it stored on my computer somewhere or is it built into the application?

Comment: Take a look at this [SO question and answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233743/change-default-winform-icon-across-entire-app)

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Those GetField methods are really interesting stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Hall got this right in his comment above.

I worded my question a little inaccurately.  I needed to match an icon in my project to that default Icon, and substituting the "SetValue" function mentioned there with the "GetValue" worked wonders:

```
  FieldInfo iconField = typeof(Form).GetField("defaultIcon",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
  myIcon = (Icon)iconField.GetValue(iconField)
```