# The most easy way to use an Icon in every form of the project

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio, icons

I wanted to make my `Icon` universal for every `Form` of my `Visual Studio` project. I googled a lot. But solutions aren't as simple as I want. Yes, simpler was to `Inherit` `Form1`. But I have used this code and I think it's most simple.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Icon icon = new Icon("resources\\icon.ico");
        this.Icon = icon;
    }
```

And in other forms I did the same:

```
public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Icon icon = new Icon("resources\\icon.ico");
        this.Icon = icon;
    }
```

And it worked absolutely. But I an not sure about the performance and need help. What do you say, is the way harmful for performance of my software? As I'm using same Icon simultaneously.

Comment: One of the problem with the above approach is: "what if you decide to use a different icon ? " . You will be required to change it in multiple places and chances are you might miss some

Comment: Is a resource file out of the question?

Comment: You may also this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233743/change-default-winform-icon-across-entire-app) and answer from Marc Gravell

Comment: @habib - Yes, that may be a problem. What if I name the new Icon icon.ico ?

Comment: @whoone, it would work, but IMO it would be a hack. I believe following the best practices will make your application more maintainable.

Comment: Tags [tag:wpf] and [tag:winforms] are usually mutually exclusive. Either the project is WPF or WinForms, and more importantly, the same question usually yields different answers. So, which one is it in your case?

Answer (score 1):

You could go with a resource file in a new icon/image project.

Create a new project as a class library and add resource files to that project as needed.  Access to the icon or any other part of the new project is made with reference to the new project.

This way you can change the actual files later and its all done in one place.
In addition you dont need to rely on a resource you find based on a string value. (I love intellisense and "[lean on the compiler](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Robert-Martin/dp/0131177052)").

Answer (score 0):

In your App.xaml file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="myIconFile.ico" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```